# When Author add new post change default status to pending

Tags: posts, functions

Same as above when Author add new post change default status to pending instead of published

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! Please read [ask] and improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set all users (authors) to *contributors*. Then they can only write posts and manage their posts but not publish them.

**Reference:** [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

[image]

Comment: Yes but then i will be not able to upload photos. Well i think i will just change it to Contributor and change the user roles to upload files using plugin